# c++: what does this operation do: float(int)

Tags: c++

what does this code do? and how can I print the int v?

```
uint8_t DHT_data[5];
int v;

v = DHT_data[2];
return float(v);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This seems like two different questions.

Comment: @PreferenceBean: can't a beginner post questions here?

Comment: Yes, but not ones that can easily be answered in a tutorial

Comment: This code uses undefined behavior so anything could happen.

Comment: @sabrina2020: Yes, of course! But nobody can post poor questions ;)

Comment: `type(value)` generally creates an object of `type` initialized with `value`. Works for `float` too.

Comment: I did not understand what float(v) does, does it convert for example the int 24 to float 24.00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are looking to read a c++ tutorial, but this code creates an empty array with room for 5 elements of type uint8_t. You then set v to the value of DHT_data[2], which is the third element of the array. On the next line, you invoke the constructor for the float data type with the value of v (which as said by NathanOliver is undefined). The new value of v as a float is returned. As for printing v, there are many methods on how to do that. The most common one is ostream::operator<<.

Answer (score 0):

`float` is different from `int` in the way that it can print decimals. For example for the number `4.23`, int would just print `4` and float would print `4.23`.
The `return float(int)` is casting the variable `v`, which was an int, to a float and is then returned.

Comment: v is not converted to a float. v is still an int. v's value is attempted to be casted to a float, which is then returned. and yes, there is a difference between what you said and my correction

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant to say. I will edit the wording.